# Excel VBA's Date() function acting up

Tags: excel, date, vba

VBA is complaining about something but I don't know what that is.

My code:

```
Sub datesnstuff()
    Const today = Now()
    Const yesterday = Date(Year(today),Month(today),Day(today) - 1)
End Sub
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
Compile error:

Expected: )
```

I think it is clear what I want it to do, but Excel is being a pain. It won't even let me use `Date(2015,1,1)`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` is a property and does not accept parameters.

You want `DateSerial()`.

Comment: So the function DATE() that I can use in a spreadsheet doesn't exist in the VBA functions?

Comment: This particular function does not (because there already is a function in VBA that does the same, even though it's named differently), but many other worksheet functions are under `Application.WorksheetFunction`.

Comment: One more thing, is there an equivalent function in VBA to NETWORKDAYS()?

Comment: This function is from the Analysis pack. First you need to make sure the "Analysis pack - VBA" add-in is enabled in Excel, then reference the `atpvbaen` from Project - References, then you can use the function.

Answer (score 1):

The `Date()` function does not take any parameters, and returns the current system date.  Try:

```
yesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, today)
```

Also, you **cannot** declare a `Const` with a function on the right hand side of the `=` sign. It must be a **constant** value.